# insert data to MS access from datagridview

Tags: datagridview

helo, i've problem with my coding, it show Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. can anyone help me..

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim item As String
    Dim qty As String
    Dim price As String

    For x As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        item = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).ToString
        qty = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).ToString
        price = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).ToString
        con.open()
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Customer", con)
        Dim str As String = "INSERT INTO Order(IDNumber, CodeDrink, Price, Quantity) VALUES(@IDNumber, @CodeDrink, @Price, @Quantity)"
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNumber", MainFrame.TextBox_Id.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeDrink", item)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", price)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", qty)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()

    Next
    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put square brackets around order.

```
insert into [order](....
```

It is a reserved word.

Comment: i try put [order], but it show "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: What does the table structure look like?

Comment: the name of table is Order and have 4 columns (IDNumber, CodeDrink, Price and Quantity)

Comment: actually, for code drink and price I use label because its fixed, and for quantity i use combo box to list down the numbers.can i get your email, so i can send the coding folder to you..

Comment: I mean the database datatypes (varchar(50), int, etc.)